# Swap function returning a number that is not in my array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, swap

I am working on a small bubble sort program in C. I am using a swap function and pointers to accomplish my task, my program runs fine. However, I have an issue. My program returns a 0 (which isn't in the array) and doesn't return a 9. I am very confused.

My array is: `int values[] = {7, 3, 9, 4, 6, 1, 2, 8, 5};`

And my two functions are:

```
void sort(){
    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < (sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0])); j++)
        {
            if(values[j] > values[j + 1]){
                swap(&values[j], &values[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}// end sort

void swap(int* i, int* j){
    int x = *i;
    *i = *j;
    *j = x;
}//end swap
```

And finally, after running my program I get:

```
Before:
7 3 9 4 6 1 2 8 5
After:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

What is the solution?

Comment: Please give your full code

Comment: You need to end the inner loop one element earlier, since you refer to `values[j+1]` inside it.  Your last iteration accesses one element past the end of the array right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your swap function is fine... the problem is that you access outside the array bounds in the inner `for` loop.  In that loop, you have `j` ranging from 0 to the last array index, so `values[j]` will be at most the last element of the array... however, you're working with *two* elements at a time, `values[j]` and `values[j+1]`... and on the last iteration, `values[j+1]` is out of bounds.

The solution is just to stop your inner loop one iteration earlier, ie.:

```
    for(j = 0; j < (sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]) - 1); j++){
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I tried
`for(j = 0; j < (sizeof(values)/sizeof(values[0]) - sizeof(values[0]); j++){`

I'm not very familiar with C quite yet, so getting the hang of it all. thank you so much